# What does this motherboard beep code mean?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

I have a Gigabyte [GA-Q77M-D2H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Q77M-D2H-rev-10) motherboard, and when I restarted the PC it made the following beep code and failed to boot (recording):

https://youtu.be/3FAaGJiNSgY

It now does this every time I try to boot the PC.  What does it mean?  Note: I've tried changing the RAM and unplugging everything except for the power, speaker, and power switch, but I still get this beep code.

Comment: https://ddr4motherboard.com/beepcodes/GIGABYTE-GA-Q77M-D2H-REV.-1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was some odd BIOS corruption in the end.  I removed the battery and booted the machine, and it booted without the beeping, then I restored the battery and now it's working again (albeit with a reset BIOS).

Comment: So did the beep codes correspond to anything in the link I posted? 10 short beeps - CMOS error?

Comment: If anything it corresponded to the memory error code (1 long and 3 short beeps) which doesn't make much sense as the memory seems fine.